# What happens to a CF manifest after a successful deployment?

Tags: deployment, cloud-foundry

I am currently tinkering with Cloud Foundry. I understand the basic principles of the tool but can't find what **cf push** actually does to a manifest file.

Does it read the file just once or is it stored as a static file with the application?

Also, is it possible to retrieve a manifest from a deployed app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cf push command reads the manifest file and uses the attribute values (instances, memory, disk etc) for the current deployment. The manifest helps to automate the app deployment. It can also be used for deploying multiple applications at once. As stated here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html, when you deploy an application for the first time, Cloud Foundry reads the variables described in the environment block of the manifest, and adds them to the environment of the container where the application is deployed. When your app is running, your environment variables can change depending on your setting. For example, if you have an auto-scaler, it could have increased/decreased your no. of instances/memory/disk (environment variables). If that is the case, when you stop and then restart an application, its environment variables persist.

The manifest file is read only when the "cf push" command is executed. As stated in the Cloud Foundry Documentation (https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html#exclude), the manifest file is just read and not actually stored as a file, hence it could not be accessed for a deployed app. However, if the purpose for accessing your manifest is to read your current environment setting, it can be accessed through the Cloud Foundry API's Get App Summary (or) Get detailed stats for a STARTED App: https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/234/